# Alphabetical complexity of algorithms.

Tags: logic, computer-science, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

I have posted elsewhere the following thought:

For first order theories, is it correct that there is a brute force algorithm that tells us the shortest proof length for any given theorem ('length' means the sum of the lengths of the formulas that appear as lines in the proof)?

With the answer being:

---

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141341/problem-of-finding-shortest-proof-how-complex-is-it"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141341/problem-of-finding-shortest-proof-how-complex-is-it%22)
There are two reasonable ways to measure the length of a proof: by steps or by symbols. For step-length, we can brute-force-search for proofs and be certain we've found the shortest one as long as our axiom system is finite - for symbol-length, we only need that the language is finite and our axiom system is computably axiomatized (e.g. PA and ZFC).

That said, in either case we have a serious issue as far as complexity is concerned: as long as our axiom system is "sufficiently rich," for every computable function F there is some theorem φ which has no proof of length ≤F(length(φ)). (Basically, we're looking at the Busy Beaver function in disguise when we talk about bounding proof searches ahead of time.)

---

With the above in mind, let us assume that a brute force algorithm doesn't exist that can circumvent the Busy Beaver function. Therefore, because of this does this necessarily mean that the alphabetical complexity of algorithms themselves are also unascertainable given the above?

Comment: A theorem is known to be provable, so we can take any proof and check every string that does not exceed this length whether it proves this theorem. So, there is an algorithm, it is however awfully slow. The busy beaver function is not computable, there is no algorithm to determine all its values.

Comment: Even if we only know that a statement is provable (without having a proof) , we can find this proof eventually by increasing the length and checking all strings until we find a proof. This is then also the shortest possible proof.

Comment: @Peter, Yes; but, the Busy Beaver function as per the above is what one has to encounter when trying to provide the shortest proof of a theorem, I think?

Comment: @ShawnW As has been said elsewhere, there is absolutely no problem with a brute-force proof search. The busy beaver function is only relevant if you want to bound the length of that search "ahead of time" - keep in mind that if I feed the brute force search approach a *non*-theorem, it will run forever without any success.

Comment: The catch is that we won't find out in a finite time in general, when a statement is true but not provable. But if it is provable, we can find the proof, but of course it can take extremely (and really extremely) long to find it and this is even the usual scenario.

Comment: Put another way, the function which sends each theorem to its shortest proof length and is undefined on the non-theorems **is partial computable** but **is not bounded by any *total* computable function**; the busy beaver function is relevant to the second claim but not the first.

Comment: I've turned my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is a confusion re: *partial* vs. *total* computable functions. *(Below I fix some "appropriate ambient axiom system," say $\mathsf{ZFC}$ - so e.g. "theorem" means "$\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem" and so on.)*

Something which is often insufficiently emphasized in my experience is the extent to which **partial** (= defined on some subset of $\mathbb{N}$), rather than total (= defined on all of $\mathbb{N}$), are the starting point in computability theory. We assign to each Turing machine $M$ the function $f_M$ whose domain $D_M$ is the set of inputs on which $M$ halts and, for $m$ in that domain, $f_M$ is the value $M$ outputs eventually on input $m$. The functions we get in this way are the **partial computable functions**. *(Really it should be "computable partial function," but oh well.)* They are generally partial functions rather than total since $M$ may not halt on all inputs (= $D_M$ may be a proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ - it could even be empty!).

Now amongst the partial computable functions, some are total (= $D_M=\mathbb{N}$) and some are not. (Meanwhile something like the Busy Beaver function is an example of a function which is total but not computable.) Totality is obviously a very nice property, but it's also very restrictive:

> **Fact 1**: There are partial computable functions which cannot be extended to any total computable function.

In fact something even more extreme (although it's ultimately due to the same underlying phenomenon) can occur:

> **Fact 2**: There are partial computable functions which cannot be *dominated* by any total computable function.

---

OK, now let's look at your question.

**The "proof length function" you're interested in is an example of Fact 2.** Specifically, via brute-force-search, the following is a **partial** computable function: $$p(\#\varphi)=\begin{cases}
\mbox{The length of the shortest $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proof of $\varphi$} & \mbox{if $\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\varphi$}\\
\uparrow & \mbox{ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

(Here "$\uparrow$" denotes "is undefined" and $\#\varphi$ is the Godel number of $\varphi$.) Note that the domain of $p$ is the set of (Godel numbers of) $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorems, which is *not* all of $\mathbb{N}$, so $p$ really is partial.

This is utterly unproblematic. Note, however, that $p$ is not always defined. This makes sense: if I try to brute-force-search for a proof of a non-theorem $\varphi$, I'll just spin my wheels forever and not get anywhere. Granted, for **some specific** non-theorems there may be an easy argument that they are not provable from $\mathsf{ZFC}$, but $(i)$ I can't expect that in general (this is a consequence of Godel's theorem) and $(ii)$ regardless of point $(i)$, such cleverness isn't something the brute-force-searching-function $p$ does.

So all that is pretty simple. When we try to relate $p$ to **total** computable functions, however, things get a bit weird. While computable, $p$ grows extremely fast: for every **total** computable function $t$ there is some $n$ such that $p(n)\downarrow>t(n)$. (Here "$\downarrow>$" means "is defined and greater than.") This may feel absurd at first, but in fact is a key point illustrating just how much more "free" partial computable functions are than total computable functions.

---

Let me sketch a proof of the claim in the previous paragraph. I'm going to avoid mentioning the Busy Beaver function since it's really only useful as an analogy, and it seems to have made things more confusing.

Suppose I had a total computable function $f$ such that whenever $\varphi$ is a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem it has a proof of length $<f(\#\varphi)$. (This is just saying that $f$ dominates $p$.) I can use this to check whether a sentence $\psi$ is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ in the first place: simply check all $\mathsf{ZFC}$-proofs of length $<f(\#\psi)$. If we find one whose conclusion is $\psi$ we know $\psi$ is a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem, and conversely if $\psi$ is a $\mathsf{ZFC}$-theorem then it has a proof of length $p(\#\psi)<f(\#\psi)$ which we will find.

But once we have an algorithm for determining whether a sentence is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$, we can solve the halting problem! Specifically, the sentence "$n$ is not in the halting problem" is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ iff $n$ is, in fact, not in the halting problem. This is because $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can "verify computations:" if a Turing machine $M$ halts on input $n$, then $\mathsf{ZFC}$ proves "$M$ halts on input $n$." (The analogous implication for "doesn't halt" is *false*, however.)

Since the halting problem is not computable, we've hit a contradiction.

---

Now you further asked how complicated $p$ is. It's a bit hard to answer this without a better sense of what is meant by "complicated," but here are some comments:

- $p$ itself is a computable function. However, since it is not dominated by any total computable function, it doesn't lie in any of the usual complexity classes $\mathsf{P,NP,EXP,...}$ in any sense.
- While $p$ is computable, we can separately ask how hard it is to dominate $p$ with a total (necessarily not computable) function. There turns out to be a very simple answer to this: the [Turing degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) of total functions dominating $p$ are exactly those which are at least as complicated as the halting problem.

Comment: When you mention point (i), that you can't expect this in general, as a consequence of Godel's theorem, what do you mean? Furthermore, when you say that "free" partial computable functions exist that are non-subject to the Busy Beaver problem, what does that render them as? Finally, are you artificially drawing this distinction between partially computable and total computable for the complexity class of NP complete or are they in separate classes?

Comment: @ShawnW I have no idea what your second or third questions mean: what do "not subject to the Busy Beaver problem" and "render them as" even mean? what's the connection with NP-completeness you see (there isn't one)? and what does "artificially" mean here? Re: your first question, the point is that from a total computable function bounding $p$ we could build a complete consistent computable theory extending $\mathsf{ZFC}$; this has been covered elsewhere on this site, and I'll add a link when I can find it.

Comment: This is something you've done in your other posts: you're throwing around computability/complexity-theoretic terminology in too vague a way to really be addressed. You should see if you can **precisely pose** one of the various questions you're asking; I think trying to do this will help clarify the issues.

Comment: I simply don't know how you are drawing or defining those boundaries for partial and total computability, WITH regards to complexity.

Comment: @ShawnW Do you know what the terms "partial computable function" and "total computable function" mean in the first place? (Meanwhile, what does "with regards to complexity" even mean?)

Comment: (@ShawnW Re: my promised link addressing the first question in your original comment to this answer, see [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3300029/28111). Note that while that question asks somewhat vaguely about wffs in formal systems, the OP clarifies in a comment that they're interested in checking theorem-hood, and that's what my answer is about.)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'm still reading your answer and have no idea how to precise myself any more than asking if the complexity can ever be determined for the Busy Beaver function, which arises due to the steps or symbols arising. Or in other words, if there's a function or algorithm that can determine the number of steps or symbols used in a TM, then does it have to be defined as an Turing Oracle?

Comment: @ShawnW "asking if the complexity can ever be determined for the Busy Beaver function" I don't know what you mean by "complexity" here. Since it's not computable it lies outside all the usual complexity classes like P, NP, EXP, etc. We can say that it is equivalent [in a precise computational sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree#Turing_equivalence) to the halting problem, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for; in particular, that notion of equivalence is extremely coarse (all computable functions are equivalent according to it).

Comment: @ShawnW I've edited my answer to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: See: https://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=2725 Very much along these lines